# IIS 7 IP Restriction WITHOUT app pool recycling?

Tags: iis, iis-7, application-pool, ip-restrictions

Im am currently restricting one or more (but not all) web sites to specific IP addresses via built in "IPv4 address and domain restrictions" using default value of "Deny". 
The issue is that every time we add an IP is that all associated app pools recycle. This can also cause issues with our shared config (web farm) as the change ripples out across the other servers. We will often add 1-8 IPs a day to this white list...

What would be the best way to restrict by IP that wont cause the app pools to recycle every time an IP is added or removed (config file change, custom handler, commercial software)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IIS6 the IP restrictions were part of the server host itself. It was part of the IIS metabase. In IIS7 this is broken out into a Http Module. This means that with the IIS7 changes to pipelines the HttpModule is specific to the site and therefore the app pool. This could explain why IIS7 causes an app pool recycle when IIS6 does not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We have implemented our own HttpModule which employs a better way to handle change to the list (stored in a separate file) which supports adding and removing of white/black list items WITHOUT causing an app recycle - very import for our busy server